# Satzbau "wird gemacht" vs. "soll gemacht werden" in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten

Tags: sentence-structure, style

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen

> Diese Fehler sind nicht Gegenstand der vorliegenden Arbeit. Daher **werden** sie an dieser Stelle nur kurz **erwähnt**.

und

> Diese Fehler sind nicht Gegenstand der vorliegenden Arbeit. Daher **sollen** sie an dieser Stelle nur kurz **erwähnt werden**.

Ich weiß nicht, ob die folgende Info für die Beantwortung dieser Frage relevant ist aber: Dieser Satz ist der letzte Satz in einem Buchkapitel, d.h. die Behandlung des Subjekts ist an der Stelle schon abgeschlossen.

Comment: Deiner Beschreibjng nach gibt es keinen bedeutenden Unterschied, nur eine Gemeinsamkeit: Beides ist falsch, solange Vergangenes in Vergangenheitsformen beschrieben werden soll. *Sollen* ist vielleicht stark genug, um Permanenz zu suggerieren, da aber nie wirklich klar ist, wer das schelten würde, stutzt man zumindest kurz. Klingt eher wie an die Prüfer gerichtet; Wäre sonst üblich der zu entschuldigenden Anführung voranzustellen.

Comment: @vectory  Von deinen fünf Zeilen habe ich jetzt genau null verstanden. Wie hast du das gemacht?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: ich drückte mich ungeschickt aus. Denn normaler weise stelle ich lieber provokante Gegenfragen oder lasse mich auf die Metaebene herab.

Comment: @vectory  Sind provokante Gegenfragen wirklich ein geeignetes Mittel der intellektuellen Debatte?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann genau dann wenn *schelten* ein gutes Wortspiel, um nicht zu sagen ein guter Reim, auf *sollen* ist. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit dass es früh zu *schallen* gestellt wurde stufe ich als sehr hoch ein. Also, nein?!? Meine Kommentar-Antwort kann so zusammengefasst werden: Ich würde a) "sollten" empfehlen, da Vergangenheit, soweit Konjunktiv dem nicht entgegensteht. b) umstellen und oder anders formulieren, (PS: notfalls verneinend "nicht weiter") c) wenn es zu umständlich ist, den Unterschied aufzudröseln, behaupten, es gäbe gar keinen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann da musst vll.t du eine Frage aufmachen :)

Comment: Die Fragestellung selbst würde ich wie @ChristianGeiselmann oder πάντα ῥεῖ beantworten. Irgendetwas anderes stört mich da logisch bzw. pragmatisch. Wurden die Fehler, um die es **nicht** gehen soll, schon klar abgegrenzt, oder soll das noch kommen? Wenn bereits geschehen, würde _Diese Fehler sind jedoch nicht Gegenstand d. vorliegenden Arbeit_ vollauf genügen, denn man muss nicht erwähnen, dass man sie erwähnt hat. Im anderen Fall vielleicht so: _... seien / sollen hier nur der Vollständigkeit halber aufgeführt / genannt / erwähnt (werden), nämlich im einzelnen ..._. (Da passt _sollen_ gut.)

Answer (score 4):

In Ergänzung der knappen und richtigen Antwort von @πάντα ῥεῖ:

Es handelt sich um eine inzwischen etwas altertümlich gewordene Ausdrucksweise. Der geneigte Leser mag sie verzeihen. Für den weniger geneigten Leser sollen im Folgenden einfachere Formulierungen gewählt werden.

Man denke in diesem Kontext aber auch an das englische "shall", das zwischen "sollen" (im Sinne einer moralischen Aufforderung), "müssen" (im Sinne einer Verpflichtung) und "werden" (im Sinne einer Zukunftsvorhersage) irisiert.

Manche Nutzer des Deutschen sehen im "sollen" des Beispielsatzes nach wie vor einen moralischen Imperativ. Andere empfinden es als synonym mit "werden". Ich hänge - im gegebenen Kontext - der zweiten Richtung an.

Schlussfolgerung darum: Die beiden Sätze können als synonym gelten. (Wie @πάντα ῥεῖ ja bereits festgestellt hatte.)

Stilistisch könnte man die "soll werden"-Formulierung heute für einen Tick zu blumig halten.

Um nun der Vollständigkeit Tribut zu zollen, soll hier auch noch eine dritte Variante vorgestellt werden:

> Diese Fehler sind nicht Gegenstand der vorliegenden Arbeit. Daher **seien** sie an dieser Stelle nur kurz erwähnt.

Comment: Irgend ein gutmeinender (hoffen wir's mal) Geist hat mir oben den Satz "Einerseits suggeriert das sollen im Beispielsatz einen moralischen Imperativ. Andererseits impliziert es heutzutage meist als Hilfsverb Aussagen zur Zukunft." hineinredigiert. Der wirft aber meine Argumentation aus der Bahn. Ich streiche ihn deswegen wieder. Der Geist möge seinen Gedanken für eine eigene Antwort verwenden!

Comment: Die Variante mit "seien" wollte ich auch anführen, bevor ich Deinen letzten Satz las. Die wäre meine erste Wahl (knapp vor sollen), wenn ich heute nochmal eine Publikation schreiben würde.

Answer (score 2):

Im Sinne der Bedeutung gibt es nicht wirklich einen Unterschied.

Die 2. Variante hört sich für mich allerdings ein wenig "gestelzt" an. Insbesondere für wissenschaftliche Arbeiten würde ich das Prinzip "kurz und knapp" bevorzugen.

Comment: Es handelt sich um eine inzwischen etwas altertümlich gewordene Ausdrucksweise. Der geneigte Leser mag sie verzeihen. Für den weniger geneigten Leser sollen im Folgenden einfachere Formulierungen gewählt werden.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann _"Für den weniger geneigten Leser sollen im Folgenden einfachere Formulierungen gewählt werden."_ => _Für den weniger geneigten Leser werden im Folgenden einfachere Formulierungen gewählt._

Comment: Ja eben. Ja eben.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Die weitere grammatikalische Analyse überlasse ich gerne Dir für eine weitere Antwort ;-D. Englisch war übrigens in der Frage nicht erwähnt (könnte aber ggf. impliziert werden).

Comment: Ich verstehe ehrlich gesagt von Grammatik nicht so viel. (Aber es ist ja alles am Fließen.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Geht mir genauso. Ich antworte hier immer eher so _aus dem Bauch heraus_ :-D.